# setOnInfoWindowClickListener is not working on some android devices

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

Earlier `setOnInfoWindowClickListener` was working fine. But from some days its not working on some android devices (perhaps on 6+). I tested on android android 5+ and lower versions and it is working.
I added my code below...don't know what is going wrong here...

```
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"marker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Please let me know if you find any error in my code. I appreciate your sugessions.

Comment: Are there any errors that appear in your console?

Comment: @Teyam No error is showing. It's just not working on 6+ android versions.

Comment: Can you say what are the devices you verified the issue on? Which version of PlayServices you use in your project and which version of PlayServices is installed on devices where you experience an issue?